# Passing list of numpy arrays to C using cython

Tags: python, c, numpy, cython

I have a list `list_of_arrays` of 3D numpy arrays that I want to pass to a C function with the template

```
int my_func_c(double **data, int **shape, int n_arrays)
```

such that

```
data[i]  : pointer to the numpy array values in list_of_arrays[i]
shape[i] : pointer to the shape of the array in list_of_arrays[i] e.g. [2,3,4]
```

How can I call `my_func_c` using a cython interface function?

My first idea was to do something like below (which works) but I feel there is a better way just using numpy arrays without mallocing and freeing.

```
# my_func_c.pyx

import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np
cimport cython
from libc.stdlib cimport malloc, free

cdef extern from "my_func.c":
    double my_func_c(double **data, int **shape, int n_arrays)

def my_func(list list_of_arrays):
    cdef int n_arrays  = len(list_of_arrays)
    cdef double **data = <double **> malloc(n_arrays*sizeof(double *))
    cdef int **shape   = <int **> malloc(n_arrays*sizeof(int *))
    cdef double x;

    cdef np.ndarray[double, ndim=3, mode="c"] temp

    for i in range(n_arrays):
        temp = list_of_arrays[i]
        data[i]  = &temp[0,0,0]
        shape[i] = <int *> malloc(3*sizeof(int))
        for j in range(3):
            shape[i][j] = list_of_arrays[i].shape[j]

    x = my_func_c(data, shape, n_arrays)

    # Free memory
    for i in range(n_arrays):
        free(shape[i])
    free(data)
    free(shape)

    return x
```

**N.B.**

To see a working example we can use a very simple function calculating the product of all the arrays in our list.

```
# my_func.c

double my_func_c(double **data, int **shape, int n_arrays) {
    int array_idx, i0, i1, i2;

    double prod = 1.0;

    // Loop over all arrays
    for (array_idx=0; array_idx<n_arrays; array_idx++) {
        for (i0=0; i0<shape[array_idx][0]; i0++) {
            for (i1=0; i1<shape[array_idx][1]; i1++) {
                for (i2=0; i2<shape[array_idx][2]; i2++) {
                    prod = prod*data[array_idx][i0*shape[array_idx][1]*shape[array_idx][2] + i1*shape[array_idx][2] + i2];
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return prod;
}
```

Create the `setup.py` file,

```
# setup.py

from distutils.core import setup
from Cython.Build import cythonize
import numpy as np

setup(
    name='my_func',
    ext_modules = cythonize("my_func_c.pyx"),
    include_dirs=[np.get_include()]
    )
```

Compile

```
python3 setup.py build_ext --inplace
```

Finally we can run a simple test

```
# test.py

import numpy as np
from my_func_c import my_func

a = [1+np.random.rand(3,1,2), 1+np.random.rand(4,5,2), 1+np.random.rand(1,2,3)]

print('Numpy product: {}'.format(np.prod([i.prod() for i in a])))
print('my_func product: {}'.format(my_func(a)))
```

using

```
python3 test.py
```

Comment: and how does it not work?

Comment: Ok one second, I will write a working example.

Comment: and what's the *output*

Comment: It seems the question is not clear enough but I'm not sure exactly how to edit it. The output in this case is essentially what we want to see. The cython function gives the same result as numpy (with some small rounding error). Its stochastic so changes each time.

What I wanted was a way to deal with lists of numpy arrays in cython without having to resort to mallocing and freeing memory.

Comment: Would you be ok with c++ or does it have be pure c?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you mean. The changes would be in the `.pyx` file.

Comment: Your data could be vector[double *]  for example and you could pass pointer to data[0] to the c-routine

Comment: @rwolst You could pass a pointer to numpy's inbuilt shape arrays rather than copying them element by element. Other than that I think your approach is pretty good.

Comment: Is the `my_func_c` interface set or can you update that?

Answer (score 5):

One alternative would be to let numpy manage your memory for you. You can do this by using numpy arrays of `np.uintp` which is an unsigned int with the same size as any pointer.

Unfortunately, this does require some type-casting (between "pointer sized int" and pointers) which is a good way of hiding logic errors, so I'm not 100% happy with it.

```
def my_func(list list_of_arrays):
    cdef int n_arrays  = len(list_of_arrays)
    cdef np.uintp_t[::1] data = np.array((n_arrays,),dtype=np.uintp)
    cdef np.uintp_t[::1] shape = np.array((n_arrays,),dtype=np.uintp)
    cdef double x;

    cdef np.ndarray[double, ndim=3, mode="c"] temp

    for i in range(n_arrays):
        temp = list_of_arrays[i]
        data[i]  = <np.uintp_t>&temp[0,0,0]
        shape[i] = <np.uintp_t>&(temp.shape[0])

    x = my_func_c(<double**>(&data[0]), <np.intp_t**>&shape[0], n_arrays)
```

(I should point out that I've only confirmed that it compiles and not tested it further, but the basic idea should be OK)

---

The way you've done it is probably a pretty sensible way. One slight simplification to your original code that should work

```
shape[i] = <np.uintp_t>&(temp.shape[0])
```

instead of `malloc` and copy. I'd also recommend putting the `free`s in a `finally` block to ensure they get run.

---

*Edit:* @ead has helpfully pointed out that the [numpy shape is stored as as `np.intp_t`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/c-api.array.html#c.PyArray_SHAPE) - i.e. an signed integer big enough to fit a pointer in, which is mostly 64bit - while `int` is usually 32 bit. Therefore, to pass the shape without copying you'd need to change your C api. Casting help makes that mistake harder to spot ("a good way of hiding logic errors")

Comment: @ead's suggestion of using C++ vectors is probably a reasonable alternative too - it has some of the advantages of my "numpy array" solution with less messy casting. I'll let him/her post it though...

Comment: In the original solution one also should check, that malloc was successful, i.e. the result isn't 0. So if c++ isn't an option, my trade-off would be casts (your solution) over "many things I should remember and do right".

Comment: actually, a point against casting would be: shape-entries are 8byte-integers, but after the cast they will be reinterpreted as 4byte-integers (at least on the most usual systems).

Comment: @ead Which is probably why OP was copying them I guess. My issue with casting is mostly that it makes it easy to make that kind of mistake. Thanks for pointing that out

Comment: So you proved yourself right:) I think a safer way to do it would be to reinterpret the reserved memory first: `cdef np.uintp_t[::1] shape_mem = np.array((n_arrays,),dtype=np.uintp); cdef int** shape=<int**>&shape_mem[0]` and then enjoy the advantages of the type safety: now `shape[i] = &temp.shape[0]` would be a compile error if `temp.shape[0]` wasn't an int.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is a good pattern to consume C-functionality from C++-code, and it can be also used here and would have two advantages:

1. Memory management is taken care of.
2. Thanks to templates, no casting needed, so we still have the safety-net of c's type safety.

To solve your problems you could use `std::vector`:

```
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np
from libcpp.vector cimport vector

cdef extern from "my_func.c":
    double my_func_c(double **data, int **shape, int n_arrays)

def my_func(list list_of_arrays):
    cdef int n_arrays  = len(list_of_arrays)
    cdef vector[double *] data
    cdef vector [vector[int]] shape_mem # for storing casted shapes
    cdef vector[int *] shape  #pointers to stored shapes
    cdef double x
    cdef np.ndarray[double, ndim=3, mode="c"] temp

    shape_mem.resize(n_arrays)  
    for i in range(n_arrays):
        print "i:", i
        temp = list_of_arrays[i]
        data.push_back(&temp[0,0,0])
        for j in range(3):
            shape_mem[i].push_back(temp.shape[j])
        shape.push_back(shape_mem[i].data())

    x = my_func_c(data.data(), shape.data(), n_arrays)

    return x
```

Also your setup would need a modification:

```
# setup.py    
from distutils.core import setup, Extension
from Cython.Build import cythonize
import numpy as np

setup(ext_modules=cythonize(Extension(
            name='my_func_c',
            language='c++',
            extra_compile_args=['-std=c++11'],
            sources = ["my_func_c.pyx", "my_func.c"],
            include_dirs=[np.get_include()]
    )))
```

I prefer to use `std::vector.data()` over `&data[0]` because the second would mean undefined behavior for empty `data`, and that is the reason we need `std=c++11` flag.

But in the end, it is for you to decide, which trade-off to make: the additional complexity of C++ (it has it own pitfalls) vs. handmade memory management vs. letting go of type safety for a short moment.