# Compiling multiple C files with Cython

Tags: cython

How do I compile using Cython, a C function from file `simulate_fast.c`, where this also depends on further C files `matrix.c` and `random_generator.c`. This seems like it must be a common use of Cython but after reading through the documentation, I still cannot figure out how to do it. My directory contains the following files

```
matrix.c
matrix.h
random_generator.c
random_generator.h
simulate_fast.c
simulate_fast.h
test.c
simulate_fast_c.pyx
setup.py
```

The `matrix.c` and `random_generator.c` files contain standalone functionality. The `simulate_fast.c` file uses both of these and contains the function I want to be exposed to Python, `simulate()`.
The `test.c` file tests that all the C functionality runs correctly i.e. I can execute

```
$ gcc test.c simulate_fast.c matrix.c random_generator.c -o test
```

to compile into a `test` executable that works.

My issue now is trying to compile this with Cython. My `.pyx` file is

```
cimport cython

cdef extern from "simulate_fast.h":
    int simulate()

def simulate_cp():
    return simulate()
```

I then use the basic `setup.py`

```
from distutils.core import setup
from Cython.Build import cythonize
from Cython.Distutils import build_ext
import numpy as np

setup(
    name='simulate_fast',
    ext_modules = cythonize(["simulate_fast_c.pyx"]),
    include_dirs=[]
)
```

However if I try and compile this using

```
python3 setup.py build_ext --inplace
```

I get an error

```
In file included from simulate_fast_c.c:492:0:
simulate_fast.h:89:28: error: field ‘RG’ has incomplete type
    struct RandomGenerator RG;
```

where structure `RandomGenerator` is declared in `random_generator.h`.

How do I tell the compiler we must also consider the `matrix` and `random_generator` files when compiling.

**Update**

If doing as `ead` said in the comments, I include `random_generator.h` and `matrix.h` in `simulate_fast.h` then the program now compiles. However when I try to import the `simulate_fast_c` module in Python I get an `ImportError`:

```
undefined symbol: simulate
```

Further, if I change the extern declaration line in `simulate_fast.pyx` to

```
cdef extern from "simulate_fast.c":
    int simulate()
```

I then get an import error

```
undefined symbol: get_random_number
```

which is a function in `random_generator.h`

Comment: It looks as if simulate_fast.h is not self-contained, include random_generator.h in simulate_fast.h

Comment: That's true although I still get an error so I can update the question. Out of curiosity, why would I need to include the `random_generator.h` in `simualte_fast.h` header when using Cython but not with gcc?

Comment: One way or another simulate_fast.c includes random_generator.h - it does not care whether it comes from simulate_fast.h or somewhere else...

Comment: I understand that (why it works), what I don't understand is why it didn't compile before with Cython yet was fine when compiling `test.c` with gcc.

Comment: Look at my setup.py in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46271641/5769463 you need to add all c-files to sources (but do not need the whole c++ stuff)

Comment: Ah, I was trying to use the `sources` previously but never in combination with including the other header files in `simulate_fast.h`. That fixed it, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cythonized module must either be linked to a shared library containing the compiled C code or embed it. One way to do the latter is to list the C sources as being an "Extension", then pass this extension to the cythonize command, as mentioned in [Cython's documentation](http://docs.cython.org/en/latest/src/reference/compilation.html)

The example `setup.py` file in the link can be summarized by (modulo the imports):

```
setup(
    ext_modules = cythonize(Extension("simulate_fast", ["matrix.c", "random_generator.c", "simulate_fast_c.pyx"]))
)
```