# cython: pass a 2D numpy array to cdef function

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array, cython

I want to pass a 2D numpy array to a cdef function, where the dimensions of the array can vary. Here's what I tried:

```
cimport numpy as cnp

input = numpy.array([[3.34, 2.2],[1.1, -0.6]])
input = input[:,:].astype(np.double)
cdef int nrows = 2
cdef int ncols = 2

# output of function
cdef cnp.ndarray[cnp.uint8_t, ndim=2] output = np.zeros((2,2), dtype=np.uint8)  

test_array(nrows, ncols, &input[0], <unsigned char**>output.data)
```

where my test_array function is:

```
cdef void test_array(Py_ssize_t nrows, Py_ssize_t ncols, double **x, unsigned char **output) nogil:

output[0][0]=1
output[1][0]=0
output[1][1]=1
output[0][1]=0
```

and my function prototype is:

```
cdef void test_array(Py_ssize_t nrows, Py_ssize_t ncols, double **x, unsigned char **output) nogil
```

When I compile, I get an error saying " Cannot take address of Python object" and pointing to `&input[0]`. That syntax works for a 1D array, but I'm not sure what the syntax is for a 2d array. I also tried `&input[0][0]` but that's wrong too.

Comment: Any chance you can make a gist or small repo with the exact content of the files you're trying to compile?

Comment: The first element of a 2D array is `[0,0]`.

Comment: I see you want to pass a pointer to `input`. This is unknown to the C part of Cython, you must pass the data as a [typed memoryview](http://docs.cython.org/en/latest/src/userguide/memoryviews.html) instead. If you give a NumPy array to a function that wants a typed memoryview, it will behave as one would expect :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is not clear what you would like to achieve:

**A:** if it should be a pure cython function then you should use [typed memory view](http://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/memoryviews.html), that means your function signature should be

```
cdef void test_array(double[:,:] x, unsigned char[:,:] output) nogil:
```

There are no `nrows`, `ncols` because the typed memory views have this information (similar to `std::vector`).

**B:** `array_test` is actually a wrapper for a c-function, which expects `double **` and `unsigned char **`, then you should take a look at this [SO-question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46240207/passing-list-of-numpy-arrays-to-c-using-cython).

---

Actually, I would like to explain, why your attempts didn't work.

First, why didn't `&input[0]` work? The real question is what is `input[0]`:

```
import numpy as np
input=np.zeros((3,3))
type(input[0])
<type 'numpy.ndarray'>
type(input[:,0])
<type 'numpy.ndarray'>
type(input[0,0])
<type 'numpy.float64'>
```

so `input` is a `numpy.ndarray` that means a python object, and cython refuses to take its address. The same is the case for the `input[0,0]` - it is a python object. No luck so far.

To get it work, you need the `input` to be a cython-numpy array (I don't know how to express it better - take a look at the example):

```
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np #that the way it is usually imported

def try_me():
    cdef np.ndarray[double, ndim=2] input = np.array([[3.34, 2.2],[1.1, -0.6]])
    cdef double *ptr1=&input[0,0]
    cdef double *ptr2=&input[1,0]
    print ptr1[0], ptr2[1] #prints 3.34 and -0.6
```

The important part: `input` is no longer considered/interpreted as a python object but as of type cython-type `np.ndarray[double, ndim=2]` and this is what makes the syntax `&input[0,0]` possible in the first place.

Maybe a more precise way to see it like: `cimport numpy` gives us additional tools in handling of numpy arrays so we can access internals which are not accessible in pure python.

However, `&input[0,0]` is not of type `double **` but of type `double *`, because `numpy.ndarray` is just a continuous chunk of memory and only the operator `[i,j]` mocks the feeling of 2d:

```
How it feels:
    A[0] -> A00 A01 A02
    A[1] -> A10 A11 A12

The real layout in the memory:
     A00 A01 A02 A10 A11 A12
```

There are no pointers to rows, but you could create them via `cdef double *ptr2=&input[row_id,0]`, how it could be handled is discussed in the [above mentioned question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46240207/passing-list-of-numpy-arrays-to-c-using-cython).

---

To say that `numpy.ndarray` is just a continuous piece of memory is a simplification - `numpy.ndarray` is quite a complicated beast! Please consider the following example:

```
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np

def try_me2():
    cdef np.ndarray[double, ndim=2] input = np.array([[1.0, 2.0],
                                                      [3.0, 4.0]])
    cdef np.ndarray[double, ndim=1] column = input[:,1]  
    cdef double *ptr = &column[0]
    print column          #prints column "2 4"
    print ptr[0],ptr[1]   #prints "2 3" and not "2 4"!
```

Now, here `input` and `column` share the same memory and in the memory `input[1][0]` is saved after `input[0][1]=column[0]` and only then `input[1][1]=column[1]`. `ptr[1]` takes the memory cell next to `input[0][1]` and this is `input[1][0]=3` and not `input[1][1]=4`.